# Can I save structs in a Mapping?

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct, memory

Is it possible to store structs in a Mapping or any dynamic memory structure in my Solidity SmartContract?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can store structs as the values of your mapping, not as the key. Here is some more info: http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/types.html#structs

```
struct Funder {
  address addr;
  uint amount;
}

struct Campaign {
  address beneficiary;
  uint fundingGoal;
  uint numFunders;
  uint amount;
  mapping (uint => Funder) funders;
}

uint numCampaigns;
mapping (uint => Campaign) campaigns;
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can.

For example, in the solidity code below. There is a struct `User` that has a mapping of `friends`, from `address` to another struct `Friend`.

Then there's a mapping of users, from `address` to `User` [note that `User` is a struct].

```
struct Friend {
    string name;
    string email;
    string phoneNumber;
}

struct User {
    string name;
    string email;
    uint256 balance;
    mapping (address => Friend) friends;
}

mapping (address => User) public users;
```

So, say a user A has friends B, C, and D. The `User` can be imagined to look like this:

```
{
    name: 'A',
    email: [email],
    balance: [balance],
    friends: {
        [address_of_friend_B]: {
            name: 'B',
            email: [email],
            phoneNumber: [phoneNumber],
        },
        [address_of_friend_C]: {
            name: 'C',
            email: [email],
            phoneNumber: [phoneNumber],
        },
        [address_of_friend_D]: {
            name: 'D',
            email: [email],
            phoneNumber: [phoneNumber],
        },
    }
}
```

And if there are many such `User` structs, say A, J, Z, ..., the mapping `users` holds them all:

```
{
    name: 'A',
    ...
    friends: {...},

    name: 'J',
    ...
    friends: {...},

    name: 'Z',
    ...
    friends: {...},
}
```

So yes, you can store structs in a mapping.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use struct in map like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract MyFriends{
    struct Friends{
        string name;
        string[] girlfriends;
        bool isSingle;
    }

    mapping(uint=>Friends) FriendsInfo;
}
```

wrong codes:

```
mapping(Friends=>uint) FriendsInfo;
```

Comment: Then how to set value and fetch value?

Comment: you need to make solidity functions to get and post data in map